# DLVM - pip install error

Tags: azure-dsvm

Trying to pip install on Azure Deep Learning VM is giving this error-

Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

```
ERROR:root:Error parsing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pbr/core.py", line 111, in pbr
    attrs = util.cfg_to_args(path, dist.script_args)
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pbr/util.py", line 267, in cfg_to_args
    wrap_commands(kwargs)
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pbr/util.py", line 569, in wrap_commands
    cmdclass = ep.resolve()
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.5.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2264, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
ImportError: No module named 'setuptools.command.build_clib'
error in setup command: Error parsing /tmp/pip-build-9ucgxr1d/cliff/setup.cfg: ImportError: No module named 'setuptools.command.build_clib'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-9ucgxr1d/cliff/
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the paths above it appears this is happenning on the Python 3.5 (`py35`) conda environment on the Linux edition of the Azure Data Science VM (DSVM) and Deep Learning VM (DLVM).

Based on the error message, the general guidance to resolve this is to update the setuptools and then try to install the library.

The commands to do that on the DSVM/DLVM on the global `py35` conda environment is:

```
sudo /anaconda/envs/py35/bin/pip install --upgrade setuptools
sudo /anaconda/envs/py35/bin/pip install  <<package name>>
```

For the root (Python 2.7) environment on the DSVM the commands are:

```
sudo /anaconda/bin/pip install --upgrade setuptools
sudo /anaconda/bin/pip install  <<package name>>
```

Hope this resolves the issue.